# Extract SVG code with all the CSS incorporated

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a SVG in my HTML page and it is being styled using CSS. For example, its `fill` is modified to `#F00` using CSS and `scaleX(-1)` transform is applied to it using CSS. Using javascript, I want to get the code for this modified SVG, such that it has the `fill` attribute set to `#F00` and the `transform` attribute is set to `scale(-1 1)` (notice that the `transform` attribute has the format consistent with SVG attribute syntax, rather than the CSS syntax).

If there was no CSS applied to the SVGElement, I would have been able to get the SVG code by fetching the `outerHTML` of the element. But that does not have the CSS style. Is there a way to get the CSS incorporated SVG natively, or is there a library that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need a library. Just manually edit your SVG in a text editor, to add a style block to it, create class definitions, copy your CSS rules into those classes, then add a class attribute to your SVG elements.

SVG elements can also have a style attribute, same as HTML elements.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50" width="100" height="50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st0 {
      fill: red;
      stroke-width: 5px;
      stroke: cyan;
    }
    .st1 {
      fill: cyan;
      stroke-width: 5px;
      stroke: red;
    }
    .st2 {
      transform: scaleX(-1);
      transform-origin: center;
    }
  </style>
  <g class="st2">
    <ellipse class="st0" cx="25" cy="25" rx="20" ry="20"/>
    <polygon class="st1" points="60,10 90,25 60,40"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While this seems to work for the children of the SVG element, what if the style needs to be applied to the SVG element itself? For example, I want to apply `transform: scaleX(-1)` to the SVG to flip it horizontally. I tried adding the `style` attribute to SVG element, but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Add a group element to contain all the other elements, then add a transform style to the group. I’ve updated my answer to demonstrate this as well.

Comment: [More on flipping SVGs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60879495/2518285).